# How to select records that are not in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to compare two tables and get the pn's that are not done or non existent.
I cant seem to find an answer online anywhere for exactly what I need. Here are the tables and the example output that I need. Thank you so much to whom ever can help me out.

Table1:

```
+------------+----------+------------+----+---------------------+
| cert       | job      | pcmk       | pn | stat                |
+------------+----------+------------+----+---------------------+
| MF21600001 | 6216     | A148       | 1  | 2015-08-14 13:20:29 |
| MF21600001 | 6216     | A148       | 2  |                     |
+------------+----------+------------+----+---------------------+
```

Table2:

```
+-----------+----------+----+
| job       | pcmk     | pn |
+-----------+----------+----+
| 6216      | A148     | 1  |
| 6216      | A148     | 2  |
| 6216      | A148     | 3  |
+-----------+----------+----+
```

Example output for rows in Table2 that are not in Table1 or status = blank/NULL:

```
+------------+------+------+----+
| cert       | job  | pcmk | pn |
+------------+------+------+----+
| MF21600001 | 6216 | A148 | 2  |
| MF21600001 | 6216 | A148 | 3  |
+------------+------+------+----+
```

OK, I took the first idea and played with it a bit.

```
SELECT Table1.cert, pninput.job, pninput.pcmk, pninput.pn, pn.stat
FROM   Table1, Table2
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   Table1
                   WHERE  Table1.pcmk = Table2.pcmk AND Table1.job = Table2.job AND Table1.stat = '')
```

However now every cert gets paired up with every pcmk and job even though every cert can only have 1 job and 1 pcmk and it also taked 35+ seconds to run

Comment: A simple sub query would work like `select * from table 1 where pm is not in (select pn from table2)`. There could be other better solutions, but this will work if performance is not an issue.

Comment: can you create table and sample data at http://sqlfiddle.com/ and share us the link.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarification: One job can have multiple `pcmk` and comparision should be done for each `pcmk`

```
SELECT t1.cert,t2.job,t2.pcmk,t2.pn
FROM table1 t1
join table2 t2 on (t1.pcmk=t2.pcmk)
WHERE (t1.pn=t2.pn and (t1.stat="" or t1.stat is null)) 
or t2.pn NOT IN(
  SELECT pn
  FROM table1
  WHERE table1.pcmk=t2.pcmk)
  group by t2.pcmk,t2.pn;
```

Assumption: Query is for single `job`. For multiple `job`, add `job` check in `where-clause`,`on-clause' and`group by` as well.

Comment: My god I think you got it, almost. in table2 each job/pn can have multiple pcmk. when playing with the link you provided, This one (Verify at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58841/16) it would only work if different pcmk's had different pn's. Here is how I changed it (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72f59/1/0) to make it work,

Comment: @DavidJansson : Your requirement cannot be met as per (sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72f59/1/0). You should use `pcmk` instead of `job` in `on-clause`, `where-clause` and `group by`. I hope i answered your query.

Comment: Also to clarify There are many jobs each job can have the same pn(production note) number but they are not related. and every PN can have multiple pcmk's.

Comment: Here, if I change the Grouping to t1.cert isntead of t2.job it works.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1e23/6/0

Comment: @DavidJansson : When you search `table1` against a particular `pn`, you check against same `pcmk and job` or something else?

Comment: yes same job and pcmk. this seems to work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22b52d/1/0 do you see a problem with it going forward?

Comment: @DavidJansson : Yes, the query will give wrong result if data is available for multiple jobs. In that case you need to put `job` as well as `pcmk` in `where-clause`,`on-clause` and `group by `.

Answer (score 1):

If I rephrase your condition, you want the rows from `table2` that don't have a corresponding row in `table` with a non-`null` status. This sounds like an `exists` condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table2
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   table1
                   WHERE  table1.pn = table2.pn AND stat IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Good try but unfortunately not quite, I think my problem is I'm asking too much I need the cert from table 1 and the "rest" from table 2 where the "rest" is either not present on table 1 or status NOT NULL on table 1

Answer (score 0):

One way you could approach this is by getting a list of `pn` values from t1 that are not null:

```
SELECT pn
FROM table1
WHERE stat IS NOT NULL;
```

Then you can pull all values from table2 that are not in that group. This will account for all `pn` values that are not in table1 at all, as well as the values that have a null status in table1:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2
WHERE pn NOT IN(
  SELECT pn
  FROM table1
  WHERE stat IS NOT NULL);
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58841/6) example.